# ssh connection and X11 server, diverse issues

Tags: networking, ssh, connection, putty

I'm using a machine in a town next to mine via ssh (with putty). I'm connecting through ssh, and after I log in that machine I start (with Xming running in my PC), a software that opens X11 window. After a few minutes (if I'm not lucky) the connection closes, and with that the software I'm using in the machine (comsol multihpysics) dies and all the work I've done there, is lost.

If I'm (very) lucky, the connection doesn't ends and I can finish my 6 hour simulation successfully, thing that happens just a few times a week.

I've errors like `"Network error: connection reset by peer"` and `"Network error:software caused connection abort"`, I mean, connection related errors.

Solutions like increasing `KeepAliveServer/KeepAliveClient time`, `using autossh` or `MyEnTunnel` doesn't work for me because with just one second with the connection down, the software closes.

I think that my ISP isn't a problem, I've a good bandwidth for this.

Comment: Why not use [`xpra`](http://xpra.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

Your ISP may or may not be the problem, as much as the ISP, to which other server is connected to. And the issue is not the bandwidth here. Rather it is the interfaces resetting due to loss of connection anywhere in the chain. Your chances of 6 hours of uninterrupted network connection, is one in four, statistically speaking. Considering these networks and connections are not of professional grade, it is a suckers bet in Las Vegas terms.

Having said that, I am assuming both sides, or at least the other server in the next town over, are/is a Linux machine. Why don't you just run the plain vncserver and connect to this machine using vncviewer ? Even if your connection gets interrupted, the GUI on the other machine will keep running and when you reconnect, you will get the same desktop with the GUI still running on it. Of course, this means, if you need to input something during the process, it will have to wait for you to reconnect before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

xwindows is a very chatty display protocol;  I've not had much luck using it over remote connections, but bandwidth has gotten better since I've last tried...   However, latency has remained pretty much constant.  If you're exceeding TCP/kernel sendQ values, your peer will reset connection.

It might serve you better to use a VNC type remote desktop instead of X-windows, as if the connection fails, your x-session will still be running on the remote machine, which you can resume where you left off when you connect again...